# What is the output when D and C on D flip flop are connected?

Tags: flipflop

What is the output when D and C on D flip flop are connected (when they are the same), what happens with set up and hold time in this case? Can someone explain this simple as possible?

Comment: "what happens" is unknown...

Comment: You violate setup and hold time. Unless of course there is enough delay in the connections between D and C not to.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the schematic of a D-Flip flop ...
[image]

You can see it is just a simple set-reset flip flop with some logic stuck on the front.

Under normal conditions, only one of those first two Nand gates will generate a 
pulse to the appropriate side of the flip-flop when the clock is pulsed. Which one it is, is determined by the state of the data line. As such, the data line needs to be established AND held while the clock pulse is processed.

If the data changes at the same time as the clock odd things will happen.

Notice the inverter in the circuit above. Because that invertor has an inherent delay, it can mean that BOTH set and reset are applied at the same time to the flip flop. The latter can then enter a metastable state and oscillate. If that happens at the lead edge it will settle out when the inputs have had time to propagate. If it happens on the falling edge of the clock, the outputs can oscillate indefinitely and their final state can not be relied upon.

---

An edge triggered D-type flip-flop / latch is even more complex and metastability can occur at the clock edge itself and stick around till the next clock and again the output is indeterminate.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Possible setup violation because data may not be stable in the setup-hold window. And hence the output Q is unpredictable. If you add a buffer in the clock path of the flip-flop, such that it introduces a delay/skew with respect to its data path, which is high enough to satisfy the setup requirements and low enough to not violate hold requirements, you should simply get a high value 1 at Q.

Comment: If setup time is 0. Does that mean that it is not violated and that Q is predictable?

Comment: That is not possible in real world. Every flip flop has a finite setup time due to its internal gate delays. But mathematically, no setup violation is there if setup time ever would become 0 and if the data path delay is less than the clock arrival time.

Comment: https://www.edn.com/design/analog/4371393/Understanding-the-basics-of-setup-and-hold-time you can read here to understand what goes on inside

Answer (score 0):

This is gray area of time interval when operation of the trigger - its resulting state - is not guaranteed. Look at [this datasheet](http://www.learn-c.com/74ls74.pdf) by Philips (you can find more on the internet). You can see the following values in the timing specification:

- t_su, set-up time nD to nCP
- t_h, hold time nD to nCP

These specify timing relationship between clock and data signals, which guarantee operation of the DFF as specified by the datasheet. Violation of these make operational guarantees, declared by the manufacturer, void.

Answer (score 0):

Setup and hold time requirements for a D flip-flop are not changed when you try connecting the D and C together. If the flop is one with a rising active clock and with a datasheet specified positive setup time requirements then the output will most likely be metastable after the clock rises. The eventual Q output state will not be predictable.

In the case where the speced setup time is zero or a negative amount and the C risetime is within the speced range then the Q output should be low after the C rises.

Comment: Can you explain me why excatly will Q be metastable if hold time and setup time are not changed?

Comment: The specs for the part are what do not change. These specs are requirements that must be provided for by the circuit design around the flop in order to provide for reliable operation. With C and D tied together you are not providing any setup time for D before rise of the clock.

Answer (score 0):

D FF uses the rising edge of CLK to save the value of D.

There are rules for max input risetime in ns / V. This reduces the effects due to minor differences in logic threshold in the same chip.

There are also parameter definitions for setup time and hold time unique to every chip design.

However D FF’s are designed to save the state just before the rising clock, so if slew rate and supply specs are satisfied, The output will always be Q=0.